# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable im trying to create this app and it give me this error f

Tags: kivy

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class IntroWindow(Screen):
    pass
class FirstWindow(Screen):
     def Analyzer(self,hbtn,t):  
        b=t
        Ane = hbtn*2 +2
        Ene=hbtn*2
        Ayne= hbtn*2 -2
    



class WindowManger(ScreenManager):


    pass
     


kv = Builder.load_file('kg.kv')



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv`enter code here`



if __name__ =='__main__':
    MyApp().run()







    
        


WindowManger:
IntroWindow:
FirstWindow:


<IntroWindow>:


    name:"Intro"
    BoxLayout:
    

       orientation:"vertical"
       size:root.width,root.height
       Label:
           text:"Welcome Could You Tell Me How Many Carboon & Hydrogen Atoms Do We Have"


       Button:

            text:"Get Started"
            on_release:app.root.current="CarboonNum"


    <FirstWindow>:
name:"CarboonNum"


GridLayout:
        cols:2
        rows:1


        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            rows:5
            
            Button:
                text:"1"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(1,"Meth")
            Button:
                text:"2"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(2,"Ith")
            Button:
                text:"3"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(3,"Prop")
            Button:
    



        text:"4"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(4,"Beuat")
            Button:
                text:"5"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(5,"Bent")
            Button:
                text:"6"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(6,"Hex")
            Button:
                text:"7"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(7,"Hept")
            Button:
                text:"8"
                on_press:root.Analyzer(8,"Oct") 
            Button:
                text:"9"                   
                on_press:root.Analyzer(9,"Sept")
            Button:
                text:"10"             
                on_press:root.Analyzer(10,"Dec")
        
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        rows:4
        
        Label:
            text:"How Many Hydrogen Atoms Do We Have?.."
        Button:
            text:"os"
            id:"ane" 
        Button:
            text:"9"
            id:"ene" 
        Button:
            text:"10" 
            id:"ayne"
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "d:\Python Expert System Sombk\import kivy.py", line 32, in 
> kv = Builder.load_file('kg.kv')
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 306, in load_file
> return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 373, in load_string
> parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 402, in **init**
> self.parse(content)
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 511, in parse
> objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
> _objects, *lines = self.parse_level(
> File "C:\Users\Osman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 674, in parse_level
> if current_property[:3] == 'on*':
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.315 seconds

Comment: Please don't add all those empty lines in your code. It makes it extremely hard to read, and makes the code unnecessarily large.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<FirstWindow>:` rule should not be indented.